# Cassandra Physical Column Sort

Tags: sorting, cassandra

Cassandra  stores column-keys of a row-key in sorted order physically.

My doubt is, how can it be sorted when the same row-key is present in multiple SSTables ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this explanation of how compaction merges data sorted by partition key within each SSTable and then consolidates SSTables into a single file is what you want to know: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_wt3_32w_zj__dml-compaction

Comment: Yes, Now its clear. After compaction when SSTables of same column families are merged the columns of same partition keys are rewritten as sorted. What if the read happens before any compaction ?